# Why edittext with set input type accepts spaces and non-english characters

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

Edittext input type is set for password. But it accepts spaces as character and non-english letters as special character. How can I disable it?

```
 mPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    mPassword.setTypeface(mUsername.getTypeface());
```

Comment: you need to write your own logic if you wish to disallow special characters. Setting EditText to type password will only mask the input with an asterisk and not perform any validations on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work your way around this:

```
mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                /** When user changed the Text */
                if(mPassword.contains(" ") || mPassword.contains(/*non-english chars*/)){
                    //set error msg
                }
                else{
                   //do stuff
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
```